# 3d to 2d tensor using tf.gather_nd in tensorflow

Tags: indexing, tensorflow

I want to extract elements from 3d-tensor to make 2d-tensor.
I have 3d-tensor (2000 X 2 X 3) and indices 1d-tensor for 3-dim (2000).
The indices tensor surely contain indices 0~2 of 2000 elements.

In fact, I want same result with `A[:,:,inds]`.
How to do this with `tf.gather_nd`, please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

If the tensor is really of size `2000 x 2 x 3`, you can use `tf.gather`:

```
a = tf.random_normal([2000, 2, 3])
b = tf.gather(a, [1007, 8, 7, 9])
b.get_shape()
TensorShape([Dimension(4), Dimension(2), Dimension(3)])
```

If it is of shape `2 x 3 x 2000`, you can either:

- change the shape to `2000 x 2 x 3` using `tf.reshape` and then do the same, as above
- use use regular python mechanism for indexing and then [pack](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pack) the tensor back:

  ```
  a = tf.random_normal([2, 3, 2000])
  indices = [1007, 8, 7, 9]
  subtensor = [a[:, :, i] for i in indices]
  b = tf.pack(subtensor, axis=2)
  b.get_shape()
  <tf.Tensor 'pack:0' shape=(2, 3, 4) dtype=float32>
  ```

Comment: thank you for answer, but what I want is gathering elements in terms of indices of 3d (0~2) not the 1d (0~2000).

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give a code example with a small matrix and expected results?